# Firefox gwt iframe

Tags: firefox, gwt, iframe

How to fix

```
Error: Permission denied to access property 'document' @ http://88.247.142.52:8080/Color/?subProgram=color&lng=en:41
```

Error on firefox, while trying to use an GWT application in an iframe from another domain.

Comment: Post the code (**not** the whole thing, only a small, relevant part) in the question. Make it so we can copy-paste it and check it out. Attach any error messages you get. Specify what have you tried in order to solve your issue.

Comment: As you requested I will diminish the code as much as I could to find the problem. and share it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a Xross-Domain Problem:

Chrome:

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://mesametal.set-soft.com/Anasayfa/en from frame with URL http://88.247.142.52:8080/Color/?subProgram=color&lng=en. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

FireFox:

```
[14:14:27.956] Error: Permission denied to access property 'document' @ http://88.247.142.52:8080/Color/?subProgram=color&lng=en:41
```

Compile the project and add it to the same server as the rest of your website. Use the new firefox DevBar or Firebug. And take a look at the error console.

Comment: WOW I think you found the problem. But Could you try it out again? I think I was adding some debug code. anyway I will try the firebug now.

Comment: My code runs on Chrome and IE but not firefox :( it gives "TypeError: style is null" error on line " 

return parseInt(style.marginLeft) + parseInt(style.borderLeftWidth);" of function "function com_google_gwt_dom_client_DOMImplMozilla_$getBodyOffsetLeft__Lcom_google_gwt_dom_client_DOMImplMozilla_2Lcom_google_gwt_dom_client_Document_2I(doc){" on XXXXXX.chace.html

Comment: I think I found a fix to the problem. 

My code runs on every web browser, except firefox.

To fix it:
I did popup the gwt-coded-iframe again, as usual my javascript (gwt) did not execute.
Then I:
right click > This frame > reload frame > and it executed.

Now I will try to find a way on the main site to call Iframe and reload it to fix this Firefox bug :(

Comment: How to fix this CORS issue in GWT even i am facing this issue?

Comment: Please find the answer here "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38239749/gwt-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource"